# Picamera Module not imported?

Tags: camera, web-interface

I am using [RPiCam_Webinterface](http://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface) for testing my camera. While Rpicam_Webinterface is working I can't use my camera to do anything else from commandline(like `raspivid` or `raspistill`). So to use `raspistill` I stop the RPiCam_Webinterface using 
`./RPi_Cam_Web_Interface_Installer.sh stop`
It stops. Now I do 
`raspistill -o 0.jpg` works fine.
But when I go in python shell and do 
`>>> import picamera`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    from picamera.camera import PiCamera   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 81, in <module>
    import mimetypes   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/mimetypes.py", line 29, in <module>
    import urllib   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 26, in <module>
    import socket   File "socket.py", line 6, in <module>
    server_socket = socket.socket() TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Why  is this happening? Is my socket being occupied (not sure the technical term to use) by RPiCam_Webinterface? Basically is RPiCam_Webinterface not allowing import of socket module ? But on stoppage it does allow `raspistill` & `raspivid`

Comment: I don't think that socket has anything to do with the camera itself; more likely it is for streaming output or something (I've never used python's `picamera` so I don't know all of what it does).  Are you saying this error *doesn't* happen if you try it before starting RPiCam_Webinterface?

Comment: Removed RPI_Cam_Webinterface still `picamera` not working. Something else is creating the problem.

Comment: I'm not really a python user so I'm not of much help beyond that, but could this be because you are using the python 3.x shell?  I know that it is not completely backward compatible with 2.x code.

Comment: So I copied the python file to an outer directory (which doesn't have RPI cam interface folder) and now its working . So there is some compatibility issue between RPi interface and picamera ?

Comment: Sounds like it could be some kind of [namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) collision -- but again I've used python so little I don't know anything about how it resolves these kinds of things.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this isn't the fault of RPi_Cam_Web_Interface (as it doesn't use Python), nor of picamera. I suspect what's going on is that you were attempting to import picamera in a directory which also contained a file named socket.py. So, picamera imports mimetypes, which imports urllib, which imports socket - that last step finds this "other" socket.py first and grabs that instead of the "official" socket and things break down after that...

Comment: I think you are right @DaveJones you can put that an answer if you want to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the issue here is that the script was being run in a directory where another `socket.py` file existed. When importing modules, Python by default looks in the current directory first. Only if the module is not found there does Python move on to search other directories (like `/usr/lib/python2.7`, etc). The module search path can be inspected as follows:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
```

Note that the first entry is blank (which means search the current directory). So, the chain of events that occurred above was as follows:

1. User runs `import picamera` in the interpreter
2. The interpreter imports picamera
3. picamera imports mimetypes
4. mimetypes imports urllib
5. urllib attempts to import socket
6. At this point the interpreter finds `socket.py` in the current directory and imports it instead of the "official" `socket.py` in the Python distribution
7. Something in `socket.py` attempts to execute `socket.socket()` to create a new socket, but the `socket.py` that got imported doesn't have a callable named "socket" and the script crashes

The morale of the story is "don't named your files after top level modules in the standard library (at least when you want to use those same modules). Admittedly this may be tricky, given the extensive nature of Python's standard library!

Answer (score 3):

Have you installed the module itself?

`sudo apt-get install python-picamera`

Or:

`sudo pip install picamera`

The second only works if you have installed `pip` with `sudo apt-get install python-pip`